# Which color i have to add on neutral grey to get white

Tags: color, gimp, color-theory

I am using gimp with a large text image. Unfortunately there is no way to change the color of the individual words.

So I changed the text color to a neutral grey (#7f7f7f) and added layers above the text and colored the words with the related colors. The layer mode is set to "color", so I get something like an color addition. Every color works fine except for white.

How do I fill a letter with white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a different color mode for the layer(s) you want to change to white. I'm not as familiar with GIMP as I am with Photoshop. but I imagine there's an option for "lighten" or "multiply". Either of those methods should work fine.

Comment: I used the layer mode value at gimp and colored it white. Thanks